# C# ASP.NET como almacenar controles(LinkButton) ya existentes en la vista en una lista para controlar sus propiedades en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

Tengo un modulo en ASP que maneja toda una sucursal y en ella manejo multiples objetos y cada uno de ellos tienen sub-objetos como listas, datos generales y datos avanzados, todos estos divididos en pestañas con sus respectivos paneles, el detalle que tengo es que los objetos tienen relaciones unos a los otros y si yo modifico algo en un sub-objeto o en el objeto en datos generales, puede que este elimine o modifique otro objeto de otra pestaña, todo depende de ciertas condiciones. El problema no es hacer cambios en otros objetos sino que para evitarme errores si entro en el modo edición (en el que modifico o agrego objetos)...

1.- Todos los botones de nuevo y edición de objetos y sub-objetos en la sucursal son visibles pero son des-habilitados.

2.- Todos los botones de confirmar cambios y cancelar cambios serán des-habilitados y ocultos en la vista a excepción del sub-objeto en el que estoy entrando en modo de edicion que esos seran habilitados y mostrados en la vista.

El problema para TODO esto por cada función del botón nuevo y el botón editar hace que ponga aproximadamente como de 40 a 50 lineas de codigo des-habilitando, habilitando, haciendo visible o ocultando botones como en 10 funciones. Para evitarme tanto embrollo trato de poner todos estos botones en 2 listas (lista de botones nuevos-editar y lista de aceptar-cancelar) y manejarlo en una función en cual solo envio los botones de aceptar y cancelar que estoy ocupando y con ello hago lo de los 2 puntos mencionados. Sin embargo al tratar de construir la lista me salen multiples errores como ... "no puedo almacenar estos controles en una lista" y efectuar los cambios en la vista.

Esto es como llamo a la funcion.

```
protected void btnAgregarObjeto1DatosGnerales_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  BtnsNuevoEditarCancelarOk(btnOkObj1DatosGnerales, btnCancelarObj1DatosGnerales);
}
```

Funcion en el que manejo los botones al entrar en modo edicion.

```
void BtnsNuevoEditarCancelarOk(LinkButton btnOk, LinkButton btnCancelar)
        {
            foreach( LinkButton btnOkCancelar in BtnsOkCancelar)
            {
                if (btnOkCancelar== btnOk || btnOkCancelar == btnCancelar)
                {
                    btnOkCancelar.Enabled = true;
                    btnOkCancelar.RemoveCssClass("disabled").RemoveCssClass("hidden");
                }
                else
                {
                    btnOkCancelar.Enabled = false;
                    btnOkCancelar.AddCssClass("disabled").AddCssClass("hidden");
                }
            }
            foreach (LinkButton btnAE in BtnsAgregarEditar)
            {
                btnAE.Enabled = false;
                btnAE.AddCssClass("disabled").RemoveCssClass("hidden");
            }
        }
```

Declaración de variables al inicio de la clase

```
    protected List<LinkButton> _BtnsOkCancelar;
    public List<LinkButton> BtnsOkCancelar
    {
        get { return _BtnsOkCancelar; }
        set { _BtnsOkCancelar = value; }
    }
    protected List<LinkButton> _BtnsAgregarEditar;
    public List<LinkButton> BtnsAgregarEditar
    {
        get { return _BtnsAgregarEditar; }
        set { _BtnsAgregarEditar = value; }
    }
```

EJEMPLO de como agrego los botones a la lista en el Page_Load

```
 _BtnsOkCancelar.Add(btnOKObjeto1DatosGnerales);
  _BtnsOkCancelar.Add(btnCancelarObjeto1DatosGnerales);

  _BtnsAgregarEditar.Add(btnAgregarObjeto1DatosGnerales);
  _BtnsAgregarEditar.Add(btnEditarObjeto1DatosGnerales);
```

Por cierto esto es solo cuando empiezo el modo edición y no cuando finalizo (en las funciones de aceptar y cancelar) debido a que ya tengo esa parte resuelto y no necesito de una lista sino de una estructura de condiciones.

Comment: Se me hizo complicado saber que queres hacer exactamente o de que forma buscar solucionar algun problema

Comment: El titulo dice lo que quiero. Poder agregar en una lista los botones y  en una funcion y ciclos cambiar sus propiedades, asp.net no me permite hacerlo por cuestion de la tecnologia web. Todo el rollo que mencione es porque siempre me preguntan "¿para que lo quieres hacer?".